# timestamp of excel to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have excel column with 2022-12-26 23:59:59 like timestamp and I want to add this data according to my local timezone to Postgres as a timestamp without timezone as a long(BIGINT) 1672117199. With which query I can achieve this?

Comment: `1672117199` is not a timestamp - that's a number

Comment: how do you want to transer this timestamp data from Excel to Postgres ? Manually ? csv file import ? API ?

Comment: I will be using csv file import.

Comment: `select to_timestamp(1672117199); 2022-12-26 20:59:59-08` as `1672117199` is an `epoch`. So import that column into a `bigint` field and then do the previous to get it into the timestamp field. I would advise a `timestamp with time zone` field to make life easier down the road.

Comment: You should be using a `timestamp` column in Postgres. https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Road to go ahead.